# Where are apps from the Windows Store installed to?

Tags: windows-8

When I download an app from the Store app, where do they go?

Comment: I know windows apps are installed in directory "c:\program files\WindowsApps" in windows 10. However Is there any way to list up all windows app installed from only "windows apps store" ?

Comment: @KJK Try 'My Library' in the Store app.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It depends on your Windows 8 version:

Consumer preview, release preview, and final version:

> C:\Program Files\WindowsApps

Developer preview:

> C:\Program Files\Applications

However, it is a hidden folder, and if you try to access it, it will be prompted to you a "Access denied" box. I never tested, but [this guide](https://www.maketecheasier.com/access-windowsapps-folder-windows-10/) says you can unblock it.

Comment: It's also in a hidden folder called `WindowsApps` in the final bits.

Comment: Note that you can't copy files from that folder from one Windows 8 install to another.  They "won't work".