# Where does the weather app in Windows 8 grab the backgrounds from?

Tags: windows-8

I would like to use the backgrounds the weather app has as backgrounds for my desktop. Where does the app get them from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version number might be different on your machine, depending on which update you have.

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.BingWeather_1.5.1.245_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\images\favoritesBackgrounds    
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.BingWeather_1.5.1.245_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\images\favoritesBackgrounds
```

You'll have to follow the instructions from this question to access them, though

> [Where are apps from the Windows Store installed to?](https://superuser.com/questions/463360/where-are-apps-from-the-windows-store-installed-to/463363#463363)

Comment: Thank you! That worked. For reference though, instead of following the guide referenced in the other question, I used the [take ownership](http://www.intowindows.com/take-ownership-of-files-and-folders-in-windows-8/) script which I already had installed.

Comment: I don't know what the guide recommends, but I changed the Owner of the folder and subfolders from `TrustedInstaller` to myself and it worked. These are some cool backgrounds, thank you!