# Where exactly are the apps saved in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, windows-store-app

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are apps from the Windows Store installed to?](https://superuser.com/questions/463360/where-are-apps-from-the-windows-store-installed-to)

Where exactly are the apps saved in Windows 8?

I have searched through the C:/Program Files and ProgramFiles(x86) and there is no sight of the programs that I installed through the Windows Store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C:\Program Files\Applications`. You have to give yourself permission to access the folder through the Security Settings tab in the Properties window.

Source: [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Tc600fxWzlY) video on YouTube.

Comment: Please summarize the instructions here. Videos might become unavailable at some point..

Comment: ok so I found the folder named: "Windows Apps" , however I tried appling the permissions (show in the video) to grant me access to the folder and yet havent been able to do so... I shows like loading but then nothing happens.

Comment: @Raykud it does open after loading all the way thru...

Comment: The folder was renamed at some point in the beta program from `Applications` to `WindowsApps`